# JBoss JMX Console - What Http Requests are being processed?

Tags: http, jboss, jmx

I am using JBoss JMX Console to monitor my Web Application.
How can i find what http requests are being processed at any point in time?

For eg: I see 25 busy theads - i want to know what http requests are these threads processing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if there is an ability to map a specific request to a thread but you can certainly see what HTTP requests are made to Tomcat using [AccessLogValve](https://community.jboss.org/thread/149621). You can probably use the timestamps to map those requests if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper;

The arduous way to do this is to examine every instance of the MBeans that have this pattern:

```
jboss.web:name=HttpRequest1,type=RequestProcessor,worker=http-0.0.0.0-18080
```

They are MBeans that represent the web request serving threads and they have an attribute called **currentQueryString** which is the query string of the request currently being processed. There are also attributes for **currentUri** and **method**. You could script the collection of this data as well.

An easier way, which is enabled in JBoss servers by default, is to use the   available at:

```
http://localhost:8080/web-console/status
```

It handily aggregates those same MBean's and reports them in one page.

There is also options for a fuller report

```
http://localhost:8080/web-console/status?full=true
```

and an XML formatted output

```
http://localhost:8080/web-console/status?XML=true
```